# Delete from elasticsearch all items where field does not match a certan value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete all items from Elasticsearch index where field time_crawl_started does NOT match a specific value. I'm using match_all query in combination with NOT filter.

This is what I got so far:

```
    $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
    $params = Array(
      'index' => ...,
      'type'  => ...
    );
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['match_all'] = Array();
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['not']['term']['time_crawl_started'] = $someDate;
    $client->deleteByQuery($params);
```

The problem is that this deletes all items, even ones having time_crawl_started set to $someDate, which is simply a datetime such as "2014-02-17 19:13:31".

How should I change this to delete only the items that don't have the correct date?

Comment: Try to use bool query with `must_not` clause instead of using `not` filter

Comment: Doesn't help... I'm still experimenting with all kinds of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that time_crawl_started field was analyzed and thus any comparison by value was wrong. I had to create index manually (as opposed to automagically by just inserting a new document into non-existing index) and specify mapping for my item type, setting 'index' => 'not_analyzed' for time_crawl_started.

And I ended up using script filter like this:

```
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['match_all'] = Array();
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['script']['script'] = "doc['time_crawl_started'].value != \"" . $someDate . "\"";
```